# bash file reading, while loop

Tags: bash, file-io, do-while

I'm sorry if this has been answered but since I'm not positive what exactly is the problem (among several possibilities) I haven't been successful in my searches.

What I want to do is take label numbers that are each written as a line in a text file, do things with files containting that label, and output the results to a file. What I have is this:

```
cat good_PFC.txt | while read line;
do  
 base_file=${line}_blah.nii.gz
 new_fa=${line}_fa_uncmasked.nii.gz
 new_tr=${line}_tr_uncmasked.nii.gz 

 if [ -e $base_file ]; then

  echo -n "$line " >> FA_unc_stats.txt
  fslstats $new_fa -M | tr '\n' ' ' >> FA_unc_stats.txt
  fslstats $new_fa -S | tr '\n' ' ' >> FA_unc_stats.txt     

 else
  echo $line "not a file"
 fi;
done
```

In which fslstats is a command that outputs numbers and good_PFC.txt is a test file containing

```
123
125
132
```

The output in FA_unc_stats.txt is

```
123 0.221061  0.097268
```

What's wrong is, the terminal correctly outputs "125 not a file", but does nothing with 132, which I know happens to point to a real file. So I believe something is wrong with the syntax in my while loop, but I don't know what! I bet it's something stupid but I just can't figure it out. Thanks!

ETA:
Fixed by adding a newline to the end of good_PFC.txt Now the problem is I need a newline written to the output file whenever I get to a new label, but it doesn't do that. I tried adding

```
echo /n >> FA_unc_stats.txt
```

first, but it prints "/n" on it's own line... I fail at newline commands!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know if the loop is being run on the last line at all? Bash may be skipping the last line due to a lack of a newline terminator. Try adding a newline to the last line in the file and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Oh this was it! Who new I needed a newline at the end of the file (well obvs. you did). Now I have a new problem writing the output... amended above.

Comment: Ok, can you amend your question and paste the output you're now getting?

Comment: Sorry, it just took longer than I thought to amend the question. Done now.

Comment: Ok, seems like the remaining problem is that you're having trouble trying to make echo print a newline. You can do just `echo` with no parameters to print a newline. `echo -n "\n"` will do it too but that's probably a little silly. I think your problem is that you were using `/n` for newline, but it's actually `\n`

Comment: Oh man, I've been at this too long, making silly mistakes. I finally figured it out by simply changing " fslstats $new_fa -S | tr '\n' ' ' >> FA_unc_stats.txt " to " fslstats $new_fa -S >> FA_unc_stats.txt " No need to print a \n at all if I let it come out naturally at the end! Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'echo $line' and you will see if the read loop is working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first pipe with

```
while read line; do
  ...
done <good_PFC.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

try putting the fslstsats commands in back ticks:

```
`fslstats $new_fa -M | tr '\n' ' ' >> FA_unc_stats.txt`
 `fslstats $new_fa -S | tr '\n' ' ' >> FA_unc_stats.txt
```

`

Comment: -1: that will attempt to execute the results of the command. The fact that the results are empty (due to the redirection) is irrelevant.